# html template load page dosnt wait validation javascript finish when submitting

Tags: javascript, html

i have simple code of form that has two inputs and submit , I do validation with JavaScript when i click submit and its working great . but when i try to add this code on the html template when I press submit should validation JavaScript run but loading page doesn't let the script end .i think there is some listener of event prevent the script to run any help thank you
error: [Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 134ms

```html
<form class="signin-form">
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="label" for="name">ID </label>
    <input type="text" id="id_pa" name ="id" class="form-control" placeholder="ID " required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label class="label" for="password">key </label>
    <input type="password" id="key" name ="key" class="form-control" placeholder="key" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button onclick="myFunction()"> Submit form</button>
</div>
```

and this is the same code outside the html template working great

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <script src="./pdf.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.14.305/pdf.worker.min.js" integrity="sha512-fahFaRPTP2xrdxAbzgG31V4Vr+Ga/hp4gQu3ZBq83bhKO10NoWfTJ20OWg9ufEyT1Y4ZyCuh9wLHY9CHi6l95Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      ID : <input type="text" id="id_pa" value="hat">
      Clé <input type="text" id="key" value="003">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <p id="res_stat"></p>
      <span id="login_failed"></span>

      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <div>

      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
         <strong>Success!</strong> Your Result will be displayed  .
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" id="redAlert">
         <strong>Sorry no results for  you!</strong> Check your ID AND KEY .
      </div>
      <script>
         $("#success-alert").hide();
         $("#redAlert").hide();
         
         function delay(time) {
           return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
         }
         
         function allm(tt ,key_fram) {
             if (tt == 200)
             {
                origin_res="fu.html?key=";
                var final_iframe =origin_res +key_fram;
         
               showAlert();
               delay(500).then(() => window.open(final_iframe));

               
         
             } else {
               redalert();
             }
         }
         
         function redalert(){
            $("#redAlert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
            $("#redAlert").slideUp(500);
         
          });   }
         
         function showAlert() {
           $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
           $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
         
         });
         
         }
         
         function myFunction() {
           var x = document.getElementById("id_pa").value;
           var y = document.getElementById("key").value;
           var key_fram =x+"_"+y
           var full_url = 'http://xxxxx-test.xxxxxxxx.com/'+ x + "_"+ y + ".pdf";
           fetch(`https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=${encodeURIComponent(full_url)}`)
           .then(response => {
           if (response.ok) return response.json()
           throw new Error('Network response was not ok.')
           })
           .then(data => { var tt = data.status.http_code; allm(tt,key_fram); /*console.log(data.contents);*/
         
         });}
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please also add the JavaScript you are working with to your question.

Comment: its just java script that check if id and key are true as i motioned the code work perfectly outside the html template

Comment: i think there is a problem with event listener who is loading load animation

Comment: Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).